# Debugging SIGSEGV in an Android app running on QNX 10.3.1

Tags: android, c++, segmentation-fault, coredump, qnx

I am currently trying to debug an Android application (written mostly in C++), whose networking code works flawlessly on Android but produces occasional SIGSEGV when this application is installed on a Blackberry with QNX 10.3.1.

I would like to obtain either a core dump or at least a good stack trace of the crash, but there does not seem to be a way to do this.

Blind alleys: * the QNX "dumper" program works only for Momentix applications, or so it seems. 
* I am not able to catch the stack traces with adb.
* Installing signal handler on the offending thread will not produce meaningful stack.

Is there any way how to obtain the state of the crashing Android application on QNX?